# Reference Equality in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin, in the tutorial example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val a: Int = 100
    val boxedA: Int? = a
    val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a

    val b: Int = 1000
    val boxedB: Int? = b
    val anotherBoxedB: Int? = b

    println(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // true
    println(boxedB === anotherBoxedB) // false
}
```

Why is the result of two comparision different?

Comment: Try it once with `b = 127` and another time with `b = 128`, then read the answer given by @YuriSchimke...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely because of the JDK implementation of Integer.valueOf

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)

> Returns an Integer instance representing the specified int value. If a new Integer instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Integer(int), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values. This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

If you decompile the method in Intellij, you'll find

```
   public static final void main() {
      int a = 100;
      Integer boxedA = Integer.valueOf(a);
      Integer anotherBoxedA = Integer.valueOf(a);
      int b = 1000;
      Integer boxedB = Integer.valueOf(b);
      Integer anotherBoxedB = Integer.valueOf(b);
      boolean var6 = boxedA == anotherBoxedA;
      boolean var7 = false;
      System.out.println(var6);
      var6 = boxedB == anotherBoxedB;
      var7 = false;
      System.out.println(var6);
   }
```

Comment: So, we should avoid using operator "===" ?, @YuriSchimke

Comment: Use it when you need it. But I've never used in 4 years of Kotlin.

Comment: I think the only time I've used it is as a short-circuit check when implementing `equals()` methods — and even then it's an optimisation that shouldn't affect the result.  Other than that, yes: you should only need it for very specialised uses.  `==` is far more useful and avoids gotchas such as shown in this question.